# Chrome Extension getElementById returning Null

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I am following the [Chrome Extension Tutorial](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted), and it works fine on pages, but on the chrome extensions page I get errors when trying to call `document.getElementById('buttonDiv`) as it returns null. Does anyone know why I am getting an error in the chrome extensions error page? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Error: [image]

options.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      button {
        height: 30px;
        width: 30px;
        outline: none;
        margin: 10px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="buttonDiv">
    </div>
    <script src="options.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

options.js

```
'use strict';
let page = document.getElementById('buttonDiv');
const kButtonColors = ['#3aa757', '#e8453c', '#f9bb2d', '#4688f1'];
function constructOptions(kButtonColors) {
  for (let item of kButtonColors) {
    let button = document.createElement('button');
    button.style.backgroundColor = item;
    button.addEventListener('click', function() {
      chrome.storage.sync.set({color: item}, function() {
        console.log('color is ' + item);
      })
    });
    page.appendChild(button);
  }
}
constructOptions(kButtonColors);
```

manifest.json:

```
{
    "name": "Getting Started Example",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Build an Extension!",
    "permissions": ["activeTab", "declarativeContent", "storage"],
    "options_page": "options.html",
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js", "options.js"],
      "persistent": false
    },
    "browser_action": {
      "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "icons": {
      "16": "images/get_started16.png",
      "32": "images/get_started32.png",
      "48": "images/get_started48.png",
      "128": "images/get_started128.png"
    },
    "manifest_version": 2
}
```

Comment: Remove "options.js" from manifest.json. The background scripts run in a hidden background page which is not related to the options page. And don't forget to click the "Clear all" button in the error list after reloading the extension.

Comment: Thank you, that was the solution!